# jquery next() not working

Tags: jquery

jquery next() is not working in my code. my html code is

```
 <a class="reply">Reply</a> 
 <div class="respond" style="display:none;">respond 1</div>      
 <a class="reply">Reply</a>
 <div class="respond" style="display:none;">respond  2</div> 
 <a class="reply">Reply</a> <
 div class="respond" style="display:none;">respond  2</div>
```

my jquery code is

```
$('.reply').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().show();
});
```

but it is not working. please me a solution

Comment: This should work, are you sure jQuery is loaded correctly? what do you mean by _it is not working_? http://jsfiddle.net/d3VGz/

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem but on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7jYp/) from your code everything is working.

Comment: This works fine http://jsfiddle.net/5Umjd/ have you checked if jQuery is loaded?

Comment: must a `<a>` not always have a href attribute, otherwise some browsers think its not a real link.

Answer (score 2):

The order of execution is important. If your jQuery code comes before the HTML to define the elements, then the code will be run before those elements exist and therefore no event handlers will actually be bound. In these cases, you need to bind an event handler for the DOM ready event using the jQuery [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, so that the elements are guaranteed to exist when the event handlers are being bound.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reply').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```